# Python - Capture string with or without specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to capture the sentence after a specific word. Each sentences are different in my code and those sentence doesn't necessarily have to have this specific word to split by. If the word doesn't appear, I just need like blank string or list.

Example 1: working

```
my_string="Python is a amazing programming language"
print(my_string.split("amazing",1)[1])

 programming language
```

Example 2:

```
my_string="Java is also a programming language."
print(my_string.split("amazing",1)[1]) # amazing word doesn't appear in the sentence. 
Error: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Output needed :empty string or list ..etc.

I tried something like this, but it still fails.

```
my_string.split("amazing",1)[1] if my_string.split("amazing",1)[1] == None else my_string.split("amazing",1)[1]
```

Comment: `if "amazing" in my_string` ...

Comment: If `amazing` doesn't appear in the sentence, then `split` returns a list with only one element -- there is no second element, and your program crashes.  You have to check first to see whether the target word appears at all.

Comment: `if specific_word in your_string: return your_string.split(specific_word)[1] else: return []` Is this what you desire to accomplish?

Comment: @kindall Thanks! This helped solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here. You can split and check the result:

```
tmp = my_string.split("amazing", 1)
result = tmp[1] if len(tmp) > 1 else ''
```

Or you can check for containment up front:

```
result = my_string.split("amazing", 1)[1] if 'amazing' in my_string else ''
```

The first option is more efficient if most of the sentences have matches, the second one if most don't.

Another option similar to the first is

```
result = my_string.split("amazing", 1)[-1]
if result == my_string:
    result = ''
```

In all cases, consider doing something equivalent to

```
result = result.lstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `.split()` argument you can specify what part of the list you want to use with either integers or slices. If you want to check a specific word in your string you can do is something like this:

```
my_str = "Python is cool"
my_str_list = my_str.split()
if 'cool' in my_str_list:
    print(my_str)`

output:
"Python is cool"
```

Otherwise, you can run a for loop in a list of strings to check if it finds the word in multiple strings.

Comment: use triple backticks before and after your answer to make a block of code =)  ``` 
search for stack overflow markup/ markdown

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirements of the question at all

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling index 1, call index -1. This calls the last item in the list.

```
my_string="Java is also a programming language."
print(my_string.split("amazing",1)[1])
```

returns ' programming language.'

Comment: You should probably show code that follows your own suggestion. Also, that won't return empty if not found.